# Why Vue watch doesnt work in case with raw object but works from function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-reactivity

I am currently developing page using vuetify v-tabs.
I am creating pages using dynamic  and passing props using v-bind
I have noticed strange behaviour when I added watch over one of the props (selectedTab) to dynamically created component. The watch does not detect changes on a prop if I am passing props like this:

```
props = { mboDetails: this.mboDetails, selectedTab:this.selectedTab }

v-bind="tab.props"
```

But instead if I pass my props like this:

```
    getTabProps(tabName: string) {
    if (tabName == 'TOTAL WEIGHT')
        return { selectedTab: this.selectedTab, mboDetailsGoalList: 
    this.mboDetailsGoalList };
    else if (tabName === 'MBO')
        return { mboDetails: this.mboDetails };
    }

    v-bind="getTabProps(tab.name)"
```

Everything works fine, can someone explain my the behaviour?

Comment: @kanuos question is why, and not, your approach doesnt work

Answer (score -1):

did you set up the watcher with a deep flag?

https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers

it may be that the reference for the object itself it's not mutating but the elements inside of it are not being tracked for changes.

Comment: it is not related to deep, because I am only changing ref of obj